# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated doesn't return

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

If I push a view onto the Navcontroller it works great and I can return from it either with code or using the Nav Controller back button.

Then I change it to present the view modally.  The preset works but I cant get it to return and dismiss the modal view.

This works... main view

```
   Tools *screen = [[Tools alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tools" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

     [mainNavController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];

    [screen release];
```

One the modal view:

```
- (IBAction)btnCancel:(id)sender {


  [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers  objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];


}
```

But then I change it to modal like this on the modal view it does not go back to the main view.

```
Tools *screen = [[Tools alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tools" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 [mainNavController presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];

  [screen release];
```

On the modal view:

```
- (IBAction)btnCancel:(id)sender {


    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

I have tried about everything I can think of, obviously I am missing something! Any ideas?

thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dismiss the modal view from self (modal view)

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `btnCancel` method actually getting called? Have you tried inserting an `NSLog` statement or breakpoint to verify that?

Your code looks right to me, so I'm wondering if you've just not hooked something up in Interface Builder.

Comment: @X Slash had the idea to not dismiss itself and that works.  I dont know why, never done it that way before.  Sure would be cool to graphically see the view stack so you knew what was happening.  Ih well another lesson learned.  thank for the ideas!

Comment: I might be wrong, but, your code should work on iOS 4, on iOS 5, I think they change their way, modalView.parentViewController (for example) most likely returns nil, hence sending any message to nil does nothing! (Untested, on top of my head, so test it for yourself)